# Load local js file while passing html string in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I wish to show some code in a SwiftUI view, and to get code-highlighting I would like to take advantage of `highlight.js`. Thus I write something like this:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Test: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HTMLText(html: """
            <html>
            <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="highlight/styles/nord.css">
            <script src="highlight/highlight.pack.js"></script>
            <script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
            </head>
            <body>
            <pre><code class="latex">
            Some $a^n$ \\TeX code
            </code></pre>
            </body>
            </html>
            """)
        }
    }
}

struct Test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Test()
    }
}
```

The `highlight.pack.js` and `nord.js` are in a local folder named `highlight`. I copied and added this folder to my Xcode project, but the above code has no effect (If I instead create a local `.html` file then it renders properly, but the content of this file should be dynamic and hence I need to do this within my project). What is the correct way to add these file into my project in order that the `html` code can find those `.js` files?

Comment: provide full path of the files instead just short path.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati Do you mean the absolute path on my Mac?

Comment: No, path from the project.   like Bundle.main.path(forResource: ofType:)

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati I think I got it wrong: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="\(Bundle.main.path(forResource: "nord", ofType: "css"))">` gives some run time error. What is the correct way to write this?

Comment: Make sure that file is added to project and .path(forResource is not returning nil